# Oracle SQL: Detecting breaks in continual spans

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table and I'm trying to detect products that have a break in its spans.

```
Product     | unit_Cost | price start date |    price end date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
product 1     15.00         01/01/2011      03/31/2011
product 1     15.00         04/01/2011      06/31/2011
product 1     15.00         07/01/2011      09/31/2011
product 1     15.00         10/01/2011      12/31/2011

product 2     10.00         01/01/2011      12/31/2011

product 3     25.00         01/01/2011      06/31/2011
product 3     25.00         10/01/2011      12/31/2011
```

So here I want it to report back product3 because we are missing the span

07/01/2011 - 09/31/2011

Any ideas on how I can do this?

EDIT: 
    Oracle Ver: 10g

```
Create Table Statement

CREATE TABLE Sandbox.TBL_PRODUCT
(
  PRODUCT_ID        VARCHAR2(13 BYTE),   
  PRODUCT           VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
  UNIT_COST         NUMBER,
  PRICE_START_DATE  DATE,
  PRICE_END_DATE    DATE
)
```

EDIT 2
    start dates and end dates cannot overlap

EDIT 3
    a span can be any two dates as long as price_end_date >= price_start_date. Equal is included since a product can be on sale for one day.

Comment: We need your query, and potentially the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table(s) involved, to be able to help you.  And the version of Oracle...  Why are people upvoting an incomplete question?!

Comment: Can the start and end dates overlap?

Comment: Are you always concerned with a single year? And suppose I have the first 6 months of a year, but nothing through the end of the year - is that possible? For example, suppose product 3 had only the first record. Should it be reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (using LEAD analytic function):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
                SELECT a.*, LEAD(price_start_date,1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY price_end_date) next_start_date 
         FROM Product a
       )
WHERE (price_end_date + 1)<> next_start_date
```

**Example with Setup**

```
        CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
          (
            PRODUCT   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
            UNIT_COST NUMBER,
            START_DATE DATE,
            END_DATE DATE
          );

        INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 1','15.00',TO_DATE('01/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('03/31/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));
        INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 1','15.00',TO_DATE('04/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('06/30/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));
        INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 1','15.00',TO_DATE('07/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('09/30/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));
        INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 1','15.00',TO_DATE('10/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('12/31/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));
        INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 2','10.00',TO_DATE('01/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('12/31/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));
        INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 3','25.00',TO_DATE('01/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('06/30/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));
        INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 3','25.00',TO_DATE('10/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('12/31/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));

SELECT *
  FROM (
                SELECT a.*, LEAD(start_date,1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY start_date) next_start_date 
                 FROM Product a
              )
WHERE (end_date + 1)<> next_start_date
```

**EDIT**:Updated the query to consider the next start_date and current end_date to avoid issues with the distribution of the data.

Comment: Why are you adding 3 months to the start date? Are you assuming the data is organized quarterly? I'm not sure that assumption is warranted. Suppose product 3 had one more record for the missing gap? Your query still reports it as missing. I think your approach is good, just needs tweaking. I think you should add one day to each end_date and check that against your next_start_date.

Comment: @DCookie: Yes I am assuming the data is organized querterly. Since OP is talking about spans there should be a pre defined period that shuold be used. If OP can provide more info on the span, the query can be easily tweaked to accomodate the spans.

Comment: Except you know the data isn't organized that way, since product 2 has one record for the whole year, and product 3 has a record for one half of the year.

Comment: INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 4','35.00',TO_DATE('01/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('06/30/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));
    INSERT INTO Product VALUES('product 4','35.00',TO_DATE('7/01/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'),TO_DATE('12/31/2011','MM/DD/RRRR'));

is detected as a break, even though it isn't I'll update the question

Comment: maybe better write that the next start date has to be the day after the end date?

Comment: +1, I think this works. I think you might need to check for end_date+1 < next_start_date.

Comment: @DCookie: Agreed. Since OP deals with the data I would leave it to OP to tweak it as necessary since there could be lot of possible scenarion.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this technique. It uses an inner query (`chronological_record`) to assign a rank to each record in the `TBL_PRODUCT` table (the rank being sorted on `start_date` within each `product`).

```
WITH
  chronological_record AS
  (
    SELECT
      product,
      unit_cost,
      start_date,
      end_date,
      (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY start_date))
          AS chronological_order
    FROM
      TBL_PRODUCT
  )

SELECT
  earlier.product,
  (earlier.end_date + 1) AS missing_period_start_date,
  (later.start_date - 1) as missing_period_end_date
FROM
  CHRONOLOGICAL_RECORD earlier
  INNER JOIN
  CHRONOLOGICAL_RECORD later
    ON
        earlier.product = later.product
      AND
        (earlier.chronological_order + 1) = later.chronological_order
WHERE
  (earlier.end_date + 1) <> later.start_date
```

In your example, the subquery (`chronological_record`) would yield something like this:

```
Product   | unit_Cost | start date | end date   | chronological_order
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
product 1    15.00      01/01/2011   03/31/2011    1
product 1    15.00      04/01/2011   06/31/2011    2
product 1    15.00      07/01/2011   09/31/2011    3
product 1    15.00      10/01/2011   12/31/2011    4

product 2    10.00      01/01/2011   12/31/2011    1

product 3    25.00      01/01/2011   06/31/2011    1
product 3    25.00      10/01/2011   12/31/2011    2
```

The main query's `INNER JOIN` effectively matches earlier records up with their next (chronologically speaking) records.

Comment: certainly works, although seems a bit of a long way round compared to using `lead(...)` or `lag(...)`?

Comment: @araqnid: To be honest, I did not know about `LEAD` or `LAG` before today. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is called `products`, your start date column is named `s` and your end date column is named `e`:

```
create view max_interval as 
select product, 
max(e) - min(s) as max_interval 
from products group by product;


create view total_days as 
select product, 
sum( e - s ) + count(product) - 1 as total_days 
from products group by product  ;
```

Then this query gives you all products with "missing" spans:

```
select a.*, b.*
from max_interval a 
left outer join total_days b 
on (a.product = b.product)
where a.max_interval <> b.total_days;
```

Since the group by is the same in both views, this of course can be combined into a single query, albeit making the solution a bit less clear:

```
select product, 
max(e) - min(s) as max_interval, 
sum( e - s ) + count(product) - 1 as total_days 
from products group by product  
having max(e) - min(s) <> sum( e - s ) + count(product) - 1;
```

But as Stephanie Page points out, that's a premature optimization; it's unlikely that you'll be scanning for breaks in continual spans all that often.

Comment: Interesting approach, although it does mean scanning the products table twice. Can't they be combined into a single query, though?

Comment: You've seen a lot of Product tables with billions of rows? What's the big deal with **TWO** scans of a table that's probably completely cached anyways. How often is a "Gap" analysis going to be run? How often are you updating "product" tables?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `exists` clause to filter for rows for which an earlier row exists, and a `not exist` clause to find rows where the previous row does not end on the current row plus one day.  For example:

```
select  *
from    TBL_PRODUCT t1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    TBL_PRODUCT t2
        where   t2.PRODUCT = t1.PRODUCT
                and t2.PRICE_END_DATE < t1.PRICE_START_DATE
        )
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    TBL_PRODUCT t3
        where   t3.PRODUCT = t1.PRODUCT
                and t3.PRICE_END_DATE + 1 = t1.PRICE_START_DATE
        );
```

This prints:

```
PRODUCT          UNIT_COST PRICE_STA PRICE_END
----------------------- ---------- --------- ---------
product 3           25 01-OCT-11 31-DEC-11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some math comparison of the ranges, assuming you fix the bad dates in your sample set:

```
SELECT PRODUCT
FROM Sandbox.TBL_PRODUCT
HAVING SUM(PRICE_END_DATE - PRICE_START_DATE + 1) < MAX(PRICE_END_DATE) - MIN(PRICE_START_DATE) + 1
GROUP BY PRODUCT
```

Which would return:

```
PRODUCT                                                                         
-----------------
product 3                                                                       
1 row selected
```